# How to convert a Video to avi xvid with custom Frame Size?

Tags: 13.10, video, convert, avi

i want to convert my movies to avi xvid with the frame size 700x292 so that i can watch it on my tv.But i don't know which software in ubuntu will help me.I tried arista transcoder but it does not have the option to resize the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install **ffmpeg** and its GUI application called **WinFF**

For compehensive use, you need to install it with following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg ffmpeg-doc libav-tools winff winff-doc winff-gtk2 checkinstall yasm texi2html libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libxvidcore-dev zlib1g-dev frei0r-plugins-dev libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libgsm1 libgsm1-dev libopenjpeg-dev libschroedinger-1.0-0 libschroedinger-dev libschroedinger-doc libspeex-dev libvdpau-dev vflib3-dev librtmp-dev libva-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libass4 libass-dev libmodplug1 libmodplug-dev libvo-aacenc0 libvo-aacenc-dev libvo-amrwbenc0 libvo-amrwbenc-dev libopenal1 libopenal-dev libavcodec-extra-53 libavdevice-extra-53 libavfilter-extra-2 libavformat-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51 libpostproc-extra-52 libswscale-extra-2
```

You can transcode the video with WinFF.

If with terminal you can done this with command:

```
ffmpeg -i [VIDEO NAME].[FORMAT] -vcodec -s mpeg4 -vpre [VIDEO PRESET EX. MEDIUM/HIGH ] -b [BANDWIDTH] -s [WIDTH]*[HEIGHT] -acodec copy [OUTPUT VIDEO NAME].avi
```

***Replace the particular phrases in [ ]***

If it is a ***mp4*** video named ***Myvideo*** and needed output video is ***Output.avi*** with preset ***medium***, ***3000k*** bitrate and size ***700x292***,

Then the command is :

```
ffmpeg -i Myvideo.mp4 -vcodec -s mpeg4 -vpre medium -b 3000k -s 700x292 -acodec copy Output.avi
```

Comment: when i try to convert using winff it shows unknown encoder libxvid

Answer (score 2):

I have found Handbrake to be a real pleasure.
https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/PictureSettings
He also has a ppa for Ubuntu.
https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases

Answer (score 1):

If your comfortable using the command line, then I highly suggest you take a look at [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) which is the best video conversion utility available on linux imo. It does not come installed automatically on Ubuntu but is available in the standard repos.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Once that's installed you can use command `avconv` to perform your video conversions. There is a whole bunch of options available for you to use which you can take a look at in the man pages (`man avconv`).